# Bash: Diff cmd in script not working as expected

Tags: bash, sh, diff

I'm writing a script to check differences in an array of files

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=("file1" "file")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  o=("$i"".copy")
  isDiff=(diff -y "$i" "$o")
  if [ -z "$isDiff" ];then
    echo "Files the same"
  else
    echo "Files different"
    #the long amount of \t are just for formatting 
    echo -e "$i \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t $o"
    echo "$isDiff"
  fi
done
```

file1 and file1.copy, and file2 and file2.copy are identical.
The commands work fine when entered individually but in a script the following output:
[image: script output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually invoking diff:

```sh
  isDiff=(diff -y "$i" "$o")
```

isDiff is an array, with elements "diff", "-y", "$i" and "$o"

When expanding an array, `$isDiff` is the same as `${isDiff[0]}`, so the test

```sh
  if [ -z "$isDiff" ];then
```

is testing if the first element of the array is empty. It is not. This is why the word "diff" shows up in your output.

Use proper command substitution syntax:

```sh
  isDiff=$(diff -y "$i" "$o")
  # .....^^.................^
```

Comment: Additionally you are defining the `o` variable as an array. Not necessary, just do `o="$i.copy"`

Comment: Yeah I copped the o variable. Can't believe I missed $isDiff. Cheers Glenn